# [Kivy][Buildozer] cannot build into its apk

Tags: python, android, kivy

I am very much beginner in Kivy Buildozer Android building.

My Work env is on Virtual Box=> RedHat Centos 8 => builodozer

Here is my buildozer.spec content:

https://github.com/georgekym/abcd/blob/master/buildozer.spec

requirements.source.kivy = /usr/app/buildozer/AndroidApplication/source_code
is where all of my custom module .py, .ttf and .png files are located. (including main.py and buildozer.sepc)

When I run these on the terminal with the command 'builozer android debug deploy run locat', results are shown as below:

https://github.com/georgekym/abcd/blob/master/terminal_error.txt

Awaiting your guidance and assists.... Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I believe that (in the `buildozer.spec` file) the `requirements.source.kivy` is intended for code that is needed for your list of `requirements`. The folder that contains your `main.py` and other source files should be specified as the `source.dir`.